# Error on animation on OnCallclick button

Tags: android

I have an error when I want to start a new thread and a button will be pressed.
Here some screenshots of the error and mpás the codes

[When I start the fragment, the button starts well, with the corresponding animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9eYo.png)

[But when I press another, this simply invalidates, when it should be like the others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohUrO.png)

Here is my code:

Initializacion button

```
destacados_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.destacados);
destacados_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
favoritos_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
en_vivo.setOnClickListener(this);
chat.setOnClickListener(this);
a_= convierte.ConvierteVectorDrawable(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "destacados_icon", destacados_btn.getContext().getTheme());
destacados_btn.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(a_, null, null, null);

@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    regresaElementoAnimado();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.destacados:
            a.iniciaAnimacion(view);
            Log.i("BOTON", "INNICIO");
            break;
        case R.id.favoritos:
            b.iniciaAnimacion(view);
            break;
        case R.id.live:
            c.iniciaAnimacion(view);
            break;
        case R.id.chat:
            d.iniciaAnimacion(view);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void regresaElementoAnimado() {
        a.quitaAnimacion();
        b.quitaAnimacion();
        c.quitaAnimacion();
        d.quitaAnimacion();
}

private final Context context;
private final Button button;
private ExpandAnimation animation;
private final String txt;
private final int color;
private final VectorDrawableCompat drawable;
private View view;

/**

 * Método que realiza cambios dinamicos al botón
 * @param context Actividad
 * @param button Aboton a trabajar
 * @param color Asignación de color
 * @param txt Texto del botón
 * @param drawable Vector icono del boton
 */

public AnimationButton(Context context, Button button, String txt, VectorDrawableCompat drawable, int color) {
    this.context = context;
    this.button = button;
    this.txt = txt;
    this.color = color;
    this.drawable = drawable;
}

public void iniciaAnimacion(View view) {
    this.view = view;
    // OvalShape, shape utilizado en el menu videos {oval_menu}
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval_menu);
    // Se le asigna a {oval_manu} color dinamicamente
    ((GradientDrawable) button.getBackground()).setColor(color);
    // Creamos una nueva animación (se desliza solo verticalmente)
    // context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.animacion_width) -> Dimensiones ó tamaño del desplazamiento la animacion
    animation = new ExpandAnimation(view, view.getBottom(), 100, 90, (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.animacion_width));
    // Asignamos duración
    animation.setDuration(300);
    // ANimación persistente hasta que termina
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    // Eventos de la animación
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // Ocultamos icono izquiero hasta que acabe la animación
            button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
            // Damos márgen izquiero para mejorar el estilo del icono izqquierdo del boton
            actualizaPadding();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // Intercambiamos colores del icono y oval_menu, también se aigna titulo al botón
            cambiaElementosBoton(Color.WHITE /* Color del drawable al quitar animacioón */,
                    drawable,/* Icono */
                    txt); /* Texto del boton */
        }
    });
    view.startAnimation(animation);
}

public void quitaAnimacion() {
    // Si hay animación existente canelala
    if(animation != null) {
        // animacion = null
        animation = null;
        // Reacomodamos márgenes
        actualizaPadding();
        // quitamos animación al botón
        view.getAnimation().cancel();
        // volvemos al estado original
        cambiaElementosBoton(color, drawable, "");
        // quitamos oval menu
        button.setBackground(null);
    }
}

/**

 * Método que realiza cambios dinamicos al botón
 * @param color Asignación de color
 * @param icono_izquiero Vector previamente trabajado para el botón (icono)
 * @param txt Texto del botón
 */
private void cambiaElementosBoton(int color, VectorDrawableCompat icono_izquiero, String txt) {
    icono_izquiero.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); // Color del icono
    button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(icono_izquiero, null, null, null);
    button.setText(txt);
}

/**

 * Márgenes en el botón
 * 25 corresponde al padding izquierdo
 */
private void actualizaPadding() {
    button.setPadding(25, 10, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can i see your log cat for the error?

Comment: this dont show any error, only dont recognize OnClick event when I use performClick or CallOnClick

Answer (score 0):

I think there is need to set setOnClickListener() method on your button then when you click on your button call onClick event.

Try this at below your button initialization:

destacados_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Where..?? Sorry, I don't see

Comment: I dont put this in example code, but in the project i define this.